# Error when running a UDF in Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to get a UDF to run in pig however I am facing some issues in that when I try and run the pig script it errors saying cannot instantiate mathPow with values ‘null’, if any body can help that would be great.

Thanks

The pig script is as follows:

```
REGISTER MathPower.jar
A = load ‘input’ using PigStorage(‘,’);
C = foreach A generate $0 as x, $1 as z;
B = foreach A generate powUDF.mathUDF(x, z);
dump B;
```

The input file contains:
2,3
4,5

The java is as follows, NO exteranl librarbies have been added, I have simply followed a tutorial. I am using java version 1.6 and eclipse:

```
package powUDF;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.*;


public class mathUDF extends EvalFunc<Long> {

/**
* A simple UDF that takes a value and raises it to the power of a second
* value.  It can be used in a Pig Latin script as Pow(x, y), where x and y
* are both expected to be ints.
*/


 public Long exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
 try {
     /* Rather than give you explicit arguments, UDFs are always handed
      * a tuple.  The UDF must know the arguments it expects and pull
      * them out of the tuple.  These next two lines get the first and
      * second fields out of the input tuple that was handed in.  Since
      * Tuple.get returns Objects, we must cast them to Integers.  If
      * the case fails, an exception will be thrown.
      */
     int base = (Integer)input.get(0);
     int exponent = (Integer)input.get(1);
     long result = 1;

     /* Probably not the most efficient method...*/
     for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
         long preresult = result;
         result *= base;
         if (preresult > result) {
             // We overflowed.  Give a warning, but do not throw an
             // exception.
             warn("Overflow!", PigWarning.TOO_LARGE_FOR_INT);
             // Returning null will indicate to Pig that we failed but
             // we want to continue execution.
             return null;
         }
     }
     return result;
 } catch (Exception e) {
     // Throwing an exception will cause the task to fail.
     throw new IOException("Something bad happened!", e);
 }
```

}
}

The stack trace is

```
Pig Stack Trace
```

---

ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'powUDF2.mathUDF' with arguments 'null'

```
Failed to parse: could not instantiate 'powUDF2.mathUDF' with arguments 'null'
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:193)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1571)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1544)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
    at       org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'powUDF2.mathUDF' with arguments 'null'
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:618)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.getFieldSchema(UserFuncExpression.java:193)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.FieldSchemaResetter.execute(SchemaResetter.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.AllSameExpressionVisitor.visit(AllSameExpressionVisitor.java:143)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.accept(UserFuncExpression.java:88)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.walk(ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.java:70)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visitAll(SchemaResetter.java:67)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:122)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:246)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:114)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOForEach.accept(LOForEach.java:76)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.expandAndResetVisitor(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildForeachOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:924)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:14195)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1623)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:799)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:517)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:184)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
    The type org.apache.commons.logging.Log cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    The import org.apache.commons.logging.Log cannot be resolved
    The type org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    PigWarning cannot be resolved to a variable

    at powUDF2.mathUDF.<init>(mathUDF.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:588)
    ... 37 more
================================================================================
```

Comment: Can you run your script again and post the exact error you get?  There is nothing called "mathPow" in what you have posted here.

Comment: Hi WinnieNicklaus, I made a mistake in my post, this is the error message i am getting. 2013-10-29 13:09:27,589 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'powUDF.mathUDF' with arguments 'null'

Comment: That's not the error I would have expected, but note that your script is incorrect -- it should read `B = foreach C`... not `B = foreach A`

Comment: Thanks for that. I was trying multiple things to try and get the script working. Still no joy.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace?  It will be given in the log file generated (e.g., pig_############.log).

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus I have added it to my initial question as it wouldn't let me add it within the comment box.

Comment: Can you double-check your UDF code and post the full, literal code you are using?  You have a syntax error: `for (int i = 0; i result) {` so the code you have shown won't even compile.

Comment: Sorry, I  didn't realise i had done that. I have edited and put the one i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your jar, you have to include all of the required libraries that are referenced by your classes.  I build with Ant to ensure that dependencies like this are managed properly.  Try running

```
jar -tf MathPower.jar
```

and see if you see the class `org/apache/commons/logging/Log` anywhere.  Your UDF imports this, but Pig can't find it, as indicated by the end of the stack trace.  Likewise, you appear to be missing the classes required for interacting with Hadoop:

```
The type org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable cannot be resolved.
```

Be sure that class is also included in the jar you build.  Alternatively, you may also be able to `REGISTER` the jar that contains the classes you want to refer to, but I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Yes I seemed to have missed that library. Silly mistake. Thanks for the help